# Exploring and analyzing Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am studying the Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain and I would like to understand if and how it is possible to **explore** and **analyze** the **data inside a Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain network**.

Is there a non-interactive way to analyze all the transactions of the blockchain locally? or even demanding the analysis to someone else? It would be great, as Ethereum allows us to do, to explore the ledger and its transactions to then focus on some specific of them.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

depends on your use case. In Hyperledger Composer, you have a Historian registry (all the transactions recorded for a business network). You can have multiple business networks to query (each BN being a view into the ledger because you've modeled the business networks and smart contract logic between those parties etc). You can use queries, REST APIs and filters to do your analysis. You could also have a 'regulator' type participant, who sees 'everything' that went on in the business network on the ledger. In Hyperledger Fabric, you can inquire of the Fabric blockchain direct, using a combination of routes: you have the Node js REST APIs https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest (these are a work in progress as it states) or you can use the  Fabric SDK for example -> https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/